# Do Interviewers Respond Back to a Thank You Note?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, job-offer

I've got a question and I would appreciate if you could share your thoughts.

I recently had an interview that I believe went well. After interview, I sent a thank you email and expressed my interest in the role. While I was not expecting a reply from the interviewers, I got reply from both of the interviewers. I just wanted to know if it is a good sign and if I should be optimistic to get an offer.
 The replies are something like

"Thank you very much for your interest and it was a pleasure talking with you too. wish you good luck! :)"

"... our discussions are progressing internally and we hope to be able to give you further information shortly. Meanwhile hope you have a good day and please feel free to get in touch if you have any question"

Comment: Did the interviewer actually write the ":)" smily face in the e-mail?

Comment: yes, she did. thats why I am getting tempted to be optimistic

Comment: As pointed out below it may be indication of more "open environment" but it still doesn't mean you're necessarily going to (or not going to) get a job offer. No alternative to waiting, unfortunately. And as pointed out all throughout the site, wait for an actual offer in writing before calling quits on the job search.

Answer (score 17):

It's impossible to tell. You did well by sending a thank-you note, but the only way you'll be able to tell if you got the job is if you get a verbal offer (Although it can be argued that even then, it is not set in stone).

I've gotten about 50/50 responses with thank you notes. That is, half don't send anything back, half do. For my most recent job, nobody responded back and I got the position, so that should tell you how much it means regarding a decision.

Comment: Lawerence- Thank you for sharing your experience. I know I have no other way but to wait and see if I get an offer but just one question: did it happen not to get a job offer for those %50s that you were responded after thank you note?

Answer (score 4):

Some companies may have internal policies discouraging interviewers outside of HR from responding directly to candidates.  This is done to ensure consistent messaging back to the candidate and to (hopefully) avoid misunderstandings. I wouldn't take a non-response as a bad sign, and I wouldn't take a response as a strong positive indicator, either.

It's *always* good to send a personalized, post-interview Thank You note.  If you really want to set yourself apart, send a handwritten one. And yes, the interviewers are likely to share them with each other so try to personalize them as much as you can.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a response that indicates to you that the company culture is warm and welcoming, and that clearly they value interviewed candidates.

However, it really should be no indication as to whether you've got the job or not - many organisations use pre-set criteria at the shortlisting and interview process, and the response gives you no indication as to how you did at that.

It does indicate though that the process was mutually positive - and therefore if you were unsuccessful to consider further application in the future.

If you're successful, taking the time to thank them before you know if you've got the job is generally considered polite / honourable - and therefore it sets you off on a good footing before you start.